# mongoose save 4 document for one call

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have some issues saving datas in my mongodb using mongoose. Here is the code that i use :

```
var amin = new User({FirstName: "Amin",LastName: "Taghikhani"});
amin.save(function (err, user) {
    if (err)
        throw err;
    user.SayHello();
});
```

but mongoose save 4 document, in my database i have 4 document by

```
FirstName: Amin, LastName: Taghikhani
```

can anyone help me why mongoose save 4 document?!

thank you for answer.

Comment: Can you make your question more clear? Do you want to save 4 documents in database call?

Comment: yes, no i don't want save 4 documents in database ,mongoose save 4 document when i call save